# Need to remove Decimal point from command output

Tags: linux, awk, numeric-data

Am facing one small issue with command trace where I am trying to find average and getting it but I need output without decimal point. Below is the sample command which is trying to read from a file with few grep conditions.

```
grep "#COMPLETE#" Requestlog1.log | grep "#O#" | awk -F"#" '{ sum += $NF; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }'
```

Am getting output `672.714`

Actual answer should be rounded off to `673`

Comment: post the initial `Requestlog1.log` fragment

Comment: i dint get you?, its a file am trying to get the output from it

Comment: your pipeline is redundant, that's why I asked to post `Requestlog1.log` fragment. You can obtain an optimized solution here (in case if you are interested in such one)

Comment: I'd suggest a clearer title, since the body says "round 672.714 (up) to 673" while the title says "remove decimal..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any `ceil` function in `awk`, but you can define one:

```
... | awk -F"#" 'function ceil(x){return (x == int(x)) ? x : int(x)+1} { sum += $NF; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print ceil(sum / n); }'
```

Note that `int()` rounds like would do `floor` in other languages.

Credits: [here](http://adhoctips.blogspot.de/2008/11/celing-in-awk.html)

Comment: @Irfan I'm glad to help. If you find the answer useful, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer ;-)

Comment: int() is equal to floor() only for positive numbers, not for negative ones.

Comment: I need one more help on this, could you please help me out to paste the output of this in excel sheet, wil be helpfull if someone helps

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your `print` with `printf "%.0f\n"`. Also note that `awk` can do `grep`'s job:

```
awk -F"#" '
  /#COMPLETE#/ && /#O#/ {sum += $NF; n++}
  END {if (n > 0) printf "%.0f\n", sum / n}'
```

It rounds to the nearest integer (x.3 to x, x.7 to x+1 (x-1 for negative numbers), x.5 to x or x+1 (x-1 for negative numbers) depending on whether x is even or odd)

Comment: Hi..i need help in above linux sentence, If ther is no value am getting empty variable is it possible to set as default 0 if ther is no value to post?

Comment: @Irfan, add a `;else print 0` in the END statement

Comment: plz help me with this command. where to put else print 0
'{if(max<$NF){max=$NF;line=$NF}}END{print line}'

Comment: got it..it worked:)